# Not recognizing Intents on a ListView ("Cannot resolve method onItemClick")

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-intent

I'm trying to implement and intent that brings a user to a new activity when they click an item on a `ListView`. It's not recognizing the `onItemClick` method and I keep getting the message

> "Cannot resolve 'onItemClick(android.widget.AdapterView>,android View.view, int, long)'

My Activity Code

```
public class LaunchActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_launch);

        String[] subjects = {"Physics", "Biology", "Economics"};
        ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, subjects);
        ListView subjectListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.subjectListView);
        subjectListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        subjectListView.setOnItemClickListener(
                new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        super.onItemClick(parent, view, position, id);

                        if (position == 0) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LaunchActivity.this, Driver.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else if (position == 1) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LaunchActivity.this, Driver.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else if (position == 2) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LaunchActivity.this, Driver.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }

                    }
                }


        );

    }


}
```

My XML file is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.owner.omegaphi.LaunchActivity">


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/subjectListView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Remove the `super.onItemClick()` call.

Comment: Thank you so much this worked.

Comment: sometimes it happen because cache issues, i get same issue and i have solved just by click on file>invalidate. then build>clean project.